# Selecting from multiple tables, and assign results to new columns

Tags: postgresql

Is it advised or even possible to select from multiple tables, and assign the results from some of the tables as new columns in the query result?

Lets say I have 3 tables: `cars`, `records`, `maintenance`

If given a cars id as '1234', I want to select `*` from `cars` with that id and create two new columns (only in result) called `race_records` and `maintenance_history` which will be an arrays of all matching rows from `records` and `maintenance`

Or do you typically make multiple separate queries in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attempt a triple join, you'll multiply your `records` rows by your `maintenance` rows (a car with 2 records and 2 maintenances spawns 4 rows, each with a combination of the two). You can use a [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) to aggregate in - technically, these aren't *separate queries*. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/QxwD-TMX):

```sql
select c.*, 
      (select array_agg(r) from records as r     where c.id=r.car_id) as records,
      (select array_agg(m) from maintenance as m where c.id=m.car_id) as maintenance
from cars as c;
```

| id | name | records | maintenance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | my car | {"(1,1234,record1)","(2,1234,record2)"} | {"(1,1234,maintenance1)","(2,1234,maintenance2)"} |

[`Array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.2.1.1.1) results in adequately typed arrays of all matching rows that let you [subscript](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING) by index and address by field (column) name:

```sql
select id,
       name, 
       pg_typeof(records), 
       records[1].title, 
       maintenance[2].description 
from(select c.*, 
            (select array_agg(r) from records as r where c.id=r.car_id) as records,
            (select array_agg(m) from maintenance as m where c.id=m.car_id) as maintenance
     from cars as c
) as subquery;
```

| id | name | pg_typeof | title | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | my car | records[] | record1 | maintenance2 |

Depending on what you do with them later, you might consider [`jsonb_object_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.15.1.2.1) instead.

---

> Is it advised or even possible to select from multiple tables, and assign the results from some of the tables as new columns in the query result?

Creating a new column based on a some sort of transformation of input values and giving it a new alias is a pretty common thing to do.

> do you typically make multiple separate queries in this case?

SQL is declarative. The main idea is that you tell the system ***what exactly*** it is that you want, and it's the system that decides ***how exactly*** to deliver it - an attempt to split the operation into "steps" goes against that idea. Ideally, if you can state your business with a single statement, you do it: the more context you give to the [planner](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-optimizer.html) about your goal, the better it can select methods to achieve it, and optimise the operation.

You *could* do it step-by-step, imperatively, but at best you'd end up manually laying out the same logic the planner can come up with on its own - you can play around with [`explain analyze`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html) and see the underlying mechanics of how your data gets processed and delivered. You can of course try and come up with faster/cheaper methods than that, in which case you're encouraged to share them and see if they can get built into PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yes, the join would be a bit lengthy... Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string_agg() to perform aggregation of row values in single column.

May below is the example could help you.

```
SELECT string_agg(name::text, ',') as new_column FROM cars;
```

Output:

```
Swift,Creta,Scorpio,Alto
```